# Sphinxsearch numbers in a range

Tags: php, html, search, sphinx

With Sphinxsearch, how could I search for numbers in a range (selected with 2 HTML inputs : min. and max.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the number an attribute
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#attributes

and then use setFilterRange

```
$cl->setFilterRange('price',intval($_GET['min']),intval($_GET['max']));
```